# Convert a PHP String to a Keycode String

Tags: php

I need to take a string and convert each character in the string to it's Keyboard code using PHP.

So for an example `Dave` would turn into `68,61,76,65`

I have a client who insist on using one of those JavaScript scramblers which converts an Email into the keycodes, then the JavaScript below re=creates the email address and add's it to the screen

`emailriddlerarray` is the user's email address with each character converted to the keycode

```
var emailriddlerarray=[68,97,118,105,100,67,64,87,101,98,114,97,103,101,111,117,115,46,99,111,109]
var encryptedemail_id50='' //variable to contain encrypted email
for (var i=0; i<emailriddlerarray.length; i++){
    encryptedemail_id50+=String.fromCharCode(emailriddlerarray[i])
}
```

Comment: Is the `ord()` function what you're looking for?

Comment: This should be easy using PHPs built in chr function, see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php

Comment: `chr()` goes the other way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`ord`](http://www.php.net/ord) function:

```
<?php
    $string = 'my@email.com';
    $decimalValues = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($string); $i++) {
        $decimalValues[] = ord($string[$i]);
    }
    echo '[' . implode(',', $decimalValues) . ']';
    //[109,121,64,101,109,97,105,108,46,99,111,109]
?>
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/Zwmot9cc)

Comment: Awesome thanks, I was thinking i might have to make a huge switch which would of been not good

Answer (score 1):

```
$hex = bin2hex("Dave"); // =44617665
$bin = hex2bin(44617665); // ="Dave"
```

Comment: It seems there is no such function, you need to get a little creative: http://goo.gl/tFzPz

Answer (score 1):

Use `ord` for this.

```
echo implode(',', array_map(function($character) {return ord($character);}, str_split($string)));
```

Comment: This will only work in PHP 5.3+ as it's using anonymous functions. Also, readability > compact code.

Comment: I like snazzy code, plus most people should be using 5.4 by now.